# Why doesn't @Size annotation work on List?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My entity property looks like this:

```
@Valid
@Size(min=1, max=16)
@ManyToMany(cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST })
@JoinTable(name="CustomerRoles",
           joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="CustomerId") },
           inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="RoleId") }
)
@JsonProperty(access=JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

@JsonIgnore
public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return this.roles;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@ApiModelProperty(notes="Roles of the customer.", required=true, value="User")
@JsonProperty("roles")
public List<String> getRolesAsStringList() {
    return this.roles.stream().map(Role::getName)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When I go to save the entity, I get the following exception:

List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 1 and 16', propertyPath=roles, rootBeanClass=class org.xxx.yyy.models.Customer, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]] with root cause

On the line RIGHT before I save in my service, I print out customer.getRoles().size() and it is = 1.

Does @Size not work on lists? I found info that seems to indicate it should.

EDIT: Service method looks like:

```
    public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) throws InvalidRolesException {
System.out.println("IN1 ==> " + customer.getRoles().size());
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

        customer.setRoles(customer.getRolesAsStringList().stream().map(role -> {
            try {
                return new Role(FindRoleByName(role), role);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                errors.add(role);
                return null;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println("IN2 ==> " + customer.getRoles().size());
        if (!errors.isEmpty())
            throw new InvalidRolesException(errors);
System.out.println("IN3 ==> " + customer.getRoles().size());
        return this.customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Don't mind the noise, that is just to massage a string array back to role objects... it prints out IN3 ==> 1.

Repo is just stock hibernate:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Can you post a brief example of your service?

Comment: @SebastianUllrich I've updated the post with the service and repo... nothing much there...

Comment: @SebastianUllrich Seems like the issue is that I'm doing = new ArrayList<Role>(); myself. When I comment out the new part and let the framework do it, it works as expected... weird...

Comment: @SebastianUllrich Hmm... nope... doesn't work either... only works with the node completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the `@ManyToMany` relation here? This should be sufficient enough:

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 16)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles;
```

Comment: I copied this example from one of my projects. Please feel free to alter the `cascade` and `fetch`strategy...

Comment: I originally thought it was because I was replacing the value of roles, but its happening even when I modify it in place.

Comment: If I put the size constraint on the Dto object, then it works... I dunno, the hibernate entity just doesn't like having the constraint on it...

Comment: Still throws the size constraint on a 1TM relationship. The problem is occurring when I'm creating a Customer object and saving rather then just reading them.